# Map Resultset value to another value while traverse

Tags: java, dictionary, resultset

Map list:

RBS(Table Value)- RoyalBankofScotland(to be mapped to result set output)

VT(Table Value)- VaccumTube(to be mapped to result set output)

We can list the value through below code in Java. How could we map the value from result set to another value which has the mapping already done below.

```
while(rs.next())

           {               
               System.out.println("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('"+rs.getString(2)+"',"+ MT+",NULL,"+rs.getString(4)+")");
               ;
           }
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('RBS',61501000,NULL,1000) 

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('VT',61501000,NULL,1000)
```

and so on.....

Instead of getting above usual output how can i get the below through result set

Result:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('RoyalBankOfScotland',61501000,NULL,1000) 

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('VaccumTube',61501000,NULL,1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for the desired output:

Assuming Map which contains mapping values - valueMap[{"RBS", "RoyalBankOfScotland"},{"VT","VaccumeTube"}]

```
while(rs.next())

       {               
           System.out.println("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('"+valueMap.get(rs.getString(2))+"',"+ MT+",NULL,"+rs.getString(4)+")");
           ;
       }
```

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: It has helped me @Khujema. Thank you so much !!

Comment: This is the map i used after you suggests! it worked. it can be marked as solved !!TreeMap vMap = new TreeMap();
        vMap.put("RBS","RoyalBankOfScotland");
        vMap.put("VT","VaccumTube");

Comment: Please upvote the answer and check green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer, to mark it as solved. Thanks!